Attach libraries to project. Connect c# with outlook 2016 and further via Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook lib
I'm trying to create script in c# to check emails on outlook group mailbox, but I have problems to connect package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook with my outlook.
I get an error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: „Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Can't find file.

Code:
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace OutlookMailChecker
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Example call to the function with a start date
            DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 1);
            CheckEmailForText("string", "string", "mailbox@outlook.com", "yes", "no", fromDate);
        }

        static void CheckEmailForText(string subjectText, string bodyText, string mailboxName, string found, string notfound, DateTime fromDate)
        {
            Application outlookApp = new Application();
            NameSpace outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

            // Use GetSharedDefaultFolder to access the group mailbox
            Recipient recipient = outlookNamespace.CreateRecipient(mailboxName);
            if (recipient.Resolve())
            {
                MAPIFolder inboxFolder = outlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
                Items mailItems = inboxFolder.Items;
            }
        }
    }
}

I've downloaded latest version of it, as well as same version by nuget, but both times I have received this error message. I'm not sure if there is a problem with proper setup of lib, or it won't work at all...
In my folder with outlook:
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c

I've got this dll, but not sure how should I attach it to the project, simple paste to Project1\bin\Debug\net8.0\ doesn't work sadly.
Is this library even valid for this kind of task? If so, how should I attach it to the project correctly?
Below csproj file, there is a high chance, that this setup is just wrong.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>6</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>9</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>00062fff-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" Version="15.0.4797.1004" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook">
      <HintPath>bin\Debug\net8.0\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


You also need add COM refrence "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library"

Hey, I've checked it, but still have same error msg, in both scenarios: with dll v15.0.0.0 from c disk added to project references, and with nugo up to date version... I guess if it's still viable package, then I'm just connecting it wrong, but can't find any particular solution for that one.
